# php mysql not save table innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

The following code is used to save data for a MyISAM table. However, if I change the table to InnoDB I can't save view anymore.

This is the code:

```
try{
// lancio di una transazione con PDO
$pdo->beginTransaction();

//Preparazione query
$q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tipomiele (nometipomiele, notetipomiele) VALUES (:nometipomiele, :notetipomiele)");

//binding
$q->bindParam(':nometipomiele', $nometipomiele);
$q->bindParam(':notetipomiele', $notetipomiele);//ricorda di "collegare" la giusta variabile al bind

//esecuzione
$q->execute(); // eseguo la query

 }
 // se qualcosa non è andato a buon fine

 // blocco catch per la gestione delle eccezioni
catch(pdoException $e) {

///personalizzazione pagine di rientro

 echo 'Attenzione: '.$e->getMessage();

  // notifica in caso di errore
  $output = "Impossibile collegarsi al Data Base, Utente o Password errati" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "prego riprovare" . $e .
              "<br>" . "<br>" . "<a href='miele.php'>Clicca QUI per ritornare alla pagina principale</a>";
    include 'errore.html.php';
        // ritorno alla situazione precedente
        $pdo->rollBack();
        exit ();
}

// ritorno alla situazione precedente
$pdo->rollBack();
```

This is an export of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tipomiele` (
  `idtipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nometipomiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `notetipomiele` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

INSERT INTO `tipomiele` (`idtipo`, `nometipomiele`, `notetipomiele`) VALUES
(6, 'GIPPOMIELE', '');

ALTER TABLE `tipomiele`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idtipo`);  

ALTER TABLE `tipomiele`
  MODIFY `idtipo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You get an Exception - what does the error message say? Also, it's `PDOException`, not `pdoException`.

Comment: Did `idtipo` used to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`?